# How to handle Ionic Content in Unit Tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, ionic3

In one of the screens of the Ionic3 app I am building I ended up with the need to tell the ion-content tag to refresh itself after a data change. This process is pretty well documented by the [Ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/) and wasn't a problem to make work. Then I started updating my tests and the fun began. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get Content to be injected into my tests.

Error:

> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined

The test suite in question:

```
import {async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, NavParams, Content} from "ionic-angular";
import {NavControllerMock} from "../../../test-config/custom-mocks/navController.mock";
import {NavParamsMock, ContentMock} from "ionic-mocks";

import {MessagingService} from "../shared/services/messaging.service";
import {MessagingServiceMock} from "../../../test-config/custom-mocks/messaging.service.mock";
import {VehicleService} from "../shared/services/vehicle.service";
import {VehicleServiceMock} from "../../../test-config/custom-mocks/vehicle.service.mock";
import {Vehicle} from "../shared/interfaces/vehicle.interface";
import {AlertButtonConfigClass} from "../shared/classes/alertConfig.class";
import {VehiclesDetailsComponent} from "../vehicles-details/vehicles-details.component";
import {UserClass} from "../shared/classes/user.class";
import {UserClassMock} from "../../../test-config/custom-mocks/user.class.mock";

import {VehiclesComponent} from "./vehicles.component";

describe('Vehicles Component', () => {
    describe('after initialization', () => {
        let fixture, component;

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations:[VehiclesComponent],
                providers :[
                    {provide:NavController, useClass:NavControllerMock},
                    {provide:NavParams, useClass:NavParamsMock},
                    {provide:MessagingService, useClass:MessagingServiceMock},
                    {provide:VehicleService, useClass:VehicleServiceMock},
                    {provide:UserClass, useClass:UserClassMock},
                    {provide:Content, useClass:ContentMock}
                ],
                schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
            }).compileComponents();
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VehiclesComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });

        it('should be defined', () => {
            expect(component).toBeDefined();
        });

        it('should be created', () => {
            expect(component instanceof VehiclesComponent).toBe(true);
        });
    });

    describe('methods', () => {
        let navController:NavController;
        let navParams:NavParams;
        let messagingService:MessagingService;
        let vehicleService:VehicleService;
        let userClass:UserClass;
        let content:Content;

        let vehiclesComponent:VehiclesComponent;

        beforeEach(() => {
            navController = NavControllerMock.instance();
            navParams = NavParamsMock.instance();
            messagingService = MessagingServiceMock.instance();
            vehicleService = VehicleServiceMock.instance();
            userClass = UserClassMock.instance();
            content = ContentMock.instance();

            vehiclesComponent = new VehiclesComponent(navController, navParams, messagingService, vehicleService, userClass);
        });

        describe('ionViewWillEnter method', () => {
            it('should be defined', () => {
                expect(vehiclesComponent.ionViewWillEnter).toBeDefined();
            });

            it('should be a function', () => {
                expect(typeof vehiclesComponent.ionViewWillEnter).toEqual('function');
            });

            it('should assign the value of UserClass.vehicleList to the local variable', () => {
                vehiclesComponent.ionViewWillEnter();
                expect(vehiclesComponent.vehicles.length).toEqual(0);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The component in question:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Content} from 'ionic-angular';

import {MessagingService} from "../shared/services/messaging.service";
import {VehiclesDetailsComponent} from "../vehicles-details/vehicles-details.component";
import {VehicleService} from "../shared/services/vehicle.service";
import {Vehicle} from "../shared/interfaces/vehicle.interface";
import {AlertButtonConfigClass} from "../shared/classes/alertConfig.class";
import {UserClass} from "../shared/classes/user.class";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'pbm-vehicles',
  templateUrl: 'vehicles.component.html'
})
export class VehiclesComponent {
    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  public vehicles: Vehicle[] = [];

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private messagingService: MessagingService, private vehicleService: VehicleService, private userClass: UserClass) {}

    ionViewWillEnter(){
        this.vehicles = this.userClass.vehicleList;
        //TODO: When ionic fixes the refresh problem that happens after adding an item to a list we should probably remove this.
        //See this issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13028
        this.content.resize();
    }

  public addNewVehicle(){
    this.navCtrl.push(VehiclesDetailsComponent, {'theVehicle': this.vehicleService.newVehicle()});
  }

  editVehicle(theVehicle:Vehicle) {
    this.navCtrl.push(VehiclesDetailsComponent, {'theVehicle': theVehicle});
  }
}
```

I can isolate the Error as happening in the last assertion of the "methods" suite. Can somebody please tell me how to get Content injected into that test? Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: On my first look, I do not see you injecting the content into your vehiclesComponent, and I do not see where you are trying to reference it.

Comment: @StevenScott I've added the component in question so that you can see where it is used. I don't need to do anything with Content in the test except have it available for the component to use. The injection is the problem. If I include it when the component is newed up in the "methods" suite I get an error about the signature not matching, which is correct.